# Can Android Auto apps be tested on actual devices?

Tags: android, google-play, android-auto

We are adding Android Auto and iOS CarPlay support to the existing Android/iOS versions of an app. We are able to successfully test the Auto application using the Android Media Browser simulator [as directed by the Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html?utm_campaign=android-auto-315#test-it).

We also have a stereo head unit that supports both Auto and CarPlay. We are able to use the CarPlay app successfully on the head unit, and we are able to use *published* Auto apps on the head unit. However, we can't see our development app on the actual device.

The Auto documentation is still a little bit thin, but I'm gathering [based on some wording I've seen](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/auto.html#opt_in) that Auto apps get some special flag (or similar) added by Google Play when they pass review:

> Before making the app available to Android Auto users, Google Play
>   submits your app for review against the Auto App Quality criteria and
>   notifies you of the result. If your app is approved, Google Play makes
>   that app available to Android Auto users.

**Based on this, is at all possible to run Auto apps on hardware before they've already been published and approved through Google Play?**

This seems like a frustrating chicken-and-egg problem. We'd like to have the confidence that things look good on actual hardware and on target devices before publishing.

Answer (score 7):

It is now possible to test your Android Auto apps on Auto-enabled head units. The procedure is to upload your app to the Play Store in an alpha channel, which you can then install to your device and test in a car. You will even receive feedback from the Auto review team for your app. [Wayne Piekarski]

Follow [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: Will internal tests bypass the guidelines check, or do I still have to wait for confirmation of the checks?

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the Desktop Head Unit (DHU) to test it in software before submitting it to the Play Store.  I used this method to make sure most of the quality issues were resolved with my app before submitting it.  The DHU does not require the apk to be signed by Google.

Also, submitting it through the store usually takes several hours before you can test.  The DHU is, obviously, immediate feedback.

Here's the link:  https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can not. It is due to the driver safety review. It will not be able to run on the real device until the app is approved.

But I think, you can contact Google and they can do something about it, if you really need to test it in your car.