# Android Auto in car test

Tags: android, android-auto

I am trying to get an app to deploy for Android Auto.  I have both my own app and the sample one from Google working with the test harness but they won't show up in the car.  Has anyone been able to test this or will we have to get it submitted to the store first?

Comment: n/m looks like this was answered:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353302/can-android-auto-apps-be-tested-on-actual-devices

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get it submitted to store first. It has to go through certification process that is more stricter as it is targeted to vehichles.

Testing is to be done using emulators given by google.